# Customize distance number \subsection

Tags: subsection, customize

Good morning.
I would like to add a 2cm space between the section number and the string, but the newcommand `\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\hspace{2cm}}` does not work.
And everything disappears on me. If I put a `%` first instead, everything works.
Where am I going wrong?
Thank you.

The source file is:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\hspace{2cm}}
\newcommand{\upsecnum}{\refstepcounter{section}}

\begin{document}
\upsecnum
\subsection{Scene}
\lipsum[2]
\subsection{Scene}
\lipsum[2]
%change from Act 1 to Act 2
\upsecnum
\subsection{Scene}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\thesubsection` controls the way the numbering itself is displayed, so by redefining it to `\hspace{2cm}` you have effectively removed displaying of the numbers.

Something like this might work better for you:

```
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thesection.\arabic{subsection}\hspace{2cm}}
```

[image: correctly numbered sections]

Answer (score 1):

If you don't use `\section`, but only subsection, you can more simply modify `\@seccntformat`. Modifying `\thesubsection` would have bad consequences on the table of contents, for instance.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\upsecnum}{\refstepcounter{section}}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{%
  \csname the#1\endcsname\hspace{2cm}% original has \quad
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\upsecnum
\subsection{Scene}

\lipsum[2]

\subsection{Scene}

\lipsum[2]

%change from Act 1 to Act 2
\upsecnum
\subsection{Scene}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that the same formatting would apply also to `\section`.

I can also propose a different way to input your text. Using a more semantic command will allow to modify its appearance in text more easily, if need arises.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\NewDocumentCommand{\scene}{t+ m}{%
  \IfBooleanT{#1}{\stepcounter{section}}%
  \subsection{#2}%
}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{%
  \csname the#1\endcsname\hspace{2cm}% original has \quad
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\scene+{Scene}
\lipsum[2]
\scene{Scene}
\lipsum[2]

%change from Act 1 to Act 2

\scene+{Scene}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```